# What is the best function name opposite to "xxx_init"?

Tags: c

When I write a C program, I often need to name a function like this: conn_pool_init (In this function, initialize the connection pool, and start it).

I often consider what is the best opposite function name. I have seen such as conn_pool_end, conn_pool_stop, or conn_pool_deinit. So I want to ask if there is a conventional name which is opposite to "xxx_init"?

Comment: conn_pool_exit is my favourite, but this is an *opinion* and not representative of any standard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In linux kernel drivers, usually you have a `module_init()` & `module_exit()` functions.

`module_init()` is where you initialize stuff and

`module_exit()` is where you clean up, free memories, destroy data structures and exit.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, for this case I use next options:

1. xxx_uninit
2. xxx_terminate
3. xxx_finish

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few more pairs of names I think are quite intuitive…

- `compose`/`decompose`
- `construct`/`deconstruct`
- `setup`/`teardown`